# markup/ css problem with IE

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a UI problem with a peel over graphic which is not displaying correctly in IE 6/7 and 8.

The markup is available here: http://www.jamesradford.net/ee/example.htm

If you view the page in firefox or google chrome it should display correctly.  With IE I get display problems.  Can anyone resolve this for me?

The red peel graphic should display in the right corner of the main panel.

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting into [Standards mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) by adding a suitable Doctype. Browsers are terribly inconsistent in Quirks mode.

Comment: sorry, in the real page I have a DTD: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: There's no need to race ahead into draft specifications.

Comment: Agreed. The simpler the better. <!DOCTYPE html> is as simple as it gets.

Comment: Who are you agreeing with? I was advising against rushing into HTML 5.

Answer (score 0):

what about, You'll have to move .SavePeelTop inside #NewDesignMain:

```
#NewDesignMain
{
margin-top: -10px;
position: relative;
}

.SavePeelTop
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

You'll have to move .SavePeelTop inside #NewDesignMain

Comment: this change to NewDesignMain and SavePeelTop doesn't work?  can you profile an example please?

Comment: changing it to right:2px; top:9px; lines it up in FF for me. if you don't mind cheating to get it to work with IE you can add *right: 10px; after the first right to use the IE hack to get it to render differently in IE. Just adjust it until it lines up

Comment: Also, I'd like to say I agree w/ @Josiah Sprague ... Whats up with the down voting?

Comment: I'd try something like 
.SavePeelTop { position: absolute; right: 2px; *right: 12px; top: 10px;}

This should line it up in FF, use the *right to adjust it so that it looks correct in IE

Comment: thanks for the help although im struggling here, does anyone have a working version?

Comment: If you put this on the page, I'd be able to help you better:

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js"></script>

from 

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: @JamesRadford I'm sorry, I can get it close but not perfect. You might really want to consider what some of the other people have said and clean up your markup. I'm sorry, I just don't have anymore time to play with this.

Comment: are you able to send me what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is incredibly complicated. IE is quirky in general. It always helps to keep your markup simple.

Do something like;

```
<wrapper>
ABC Test Another 100 200 total whatnot
<peel>
Save 29%
</peel>
</wrapper>
```

Not valid HTML, obviously, just a rough sketch to give you an idea. Then with CSS set `position:relative;` on the wrapper, and `position:absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` on the peel. Then you'll be good to go in all browsers.

You've used way more divs than you need, and quite a few nested elements. Always remember the K.I.S.S. philosophy. (Keep It Simple, Son)